# Magento:Adding store credit to customers grid

Tags: magento

I have tried to add customer balance (store credit) column to the customer grid in Magento admin panel. It works fine, but when I tried to search by customer balance by enterinng 'From:' and 'To:' values, it throws an error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in …./app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816"”

I have edit the below file:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php

```
     protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
$collection = -----------
------------------------
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('balance_table'=>'enterprise_customerbalance'),
              'e.entity_id = balance_table.customer_id', array('balance_table.*'));
           $collection->addAttributeToSelect('amount');           
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
---------------------
---------------------
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
----------------------
 $this->addColumn('amount', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Store Credit'),
            'index'     => 'amount',
            'type'      => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code'           
        ));
----------------------
}
----------------------
```

Any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding `'filter_index' => 'balance_table.amount',`

```
    $this->addColumn('amount', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Store Credit'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'width'     => '20px',
        'index'     => 'amount',
        'filter_index' => 'balance_table. amount',
    ));
```